# Running EMR Spark With Multiple S3 Accounts

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have an EMR Spark Job that needs to read data from S3 on one account and write to another.
I split my job into two steps.

1. read data from the S3 (no credentials required because my EMR cluster is in the same account).
2. read data in the local HDFS created by step 1 and write it to an S3 bucket in another account.

I've attempted setting the `hadoopConfiguration`:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "<your access key>")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","<your secretkey>")
```

And exporting the keys on the cluster:

```
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
```

I've tried both **cluster** and **client** mode as well as **spark-shell** with no luck.

Each of them returns an error:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
Access Denied
```

Comment: Be careful -- it looks like `fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId` only applies to files accessed via `s3n://bucket/file`. That might not be how your system is reading from S3. See: [Hadoop-AWS module: Integration with Amazon Web Services](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html).

Comment: Your statement "First, read data from the S3 ( no credentials required because my EMR cluster is in the same account )" is not quite accurate. The EMR cluster *does* require credentials to access Amazon S3 content. Credentials are passed-in via the Role associated with the cluster nodes. It is giving access to your own S3 buckets.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple.

Firstly, EMR clusters have two roles:

- A **service role** (`EMR_DefaultRole`) that grants permissions to the EMR service (eg for launching Amazon EC2 instances)
- An **EC2 role** (`EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`) that is attached to EC2 instances launched in the cluster, giving them access to AWS credentials (see [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to Applications Running on Amazon EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html))

These roles are explained in: [Default IAM Roles for Amazon EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles-defaultroles.html)

Therefore, each EC2 instance launched in the cluster is assigned the `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` role, which **makes temporary credentials available via the Instance Metadata service**. (For an explanation of how this works, see: [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).) Amazon EMR nodes use these credentials to access AWS services such as S3, SNS, SQS, CloudWatch and DynamoDB.

Secondly, you will need to **add permissions to the Amazon S3 bucket in the other account** to permit access via the `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` role. This can be done by adding a **bucket policy** to the S3 bucket (here named `other-account-bucket`) like this:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::other-account-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::other-account-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-NUMBER:role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy grants all S3 permissions (`s3:*`) to the `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` role that belongs to the account matching the `ACCOUNT-NUMBER` in the policy, which should be the account in which the EMR cluster was launched. Be careful when granting such permissions -- you might want to grant permissions only to `GetObject` rather than granting all S3 permissions.

**That's all!** The bucket in the other account will now accept requests from the EMR nodes because they are using the `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` role.

**Disclaimer:** I tested the above by creating a bucket in Account-A and assigning permissions (as shown above) to a role in Account-B. An EC2 instance was launched in Account-B with that role. I was able to access the bucket from the EC2 instance via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). I did *not* test it within EMR, however it *should* work the same way.

Comment: In addition to `s3:GetObject` permissions, you probably need to grant `s3:ListBucket` permissions on the bucket you wish to use.  (And if your bucket is KMS encrypted don't forget KMS permissions).

Comment: mate, you saved me

Answer (score 4):

Using spark you can also use assume role to access an s3 bucket in another account but using an IAM Role in the other account.  This makes it easier for the other account owner to manage the permissions provided to the spark job.  Managing access via s3 bucket policies can be a pain as access rights are distributed to multiple locations rather than all contained within a single IAM role.

Here is the `hadoopConfiguration`:

```
"fs.s3a.credentialsType" -> "AssumeRole",
"fs.s3a.stsAssumeRole.arn" -> "arn:aws:iam::<<AWSAccount>>:role/<<crossaccount-role>>",
"fs.s3a.impl" -> "com.databricks.s3a.S3AFileSystem",
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm" -> "aws:kms",
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-kms-master-key-id" -> "arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-2:<<AWSAccount>>:key/<<KMS Key ID>>"
```

External IDs can also be used as a passphrase:

```
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.stsAssumeRole.externalId" -> "GUID created by other account owner"
```

We were using databricks for the above have not tried using EMR yet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to assign an IAM role to your compute nodes (you probably already have done this), then grant cross-account access to that role via IAM on the "Remote" account. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html for the details.

Answer (score 0):

For controlling access of the resources, generally IAM roles are managed as a standard practice. Assume roles are used when you want to access resources in a different account. If you or your organisation follow the same then you should follow https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/securely-analyze-data-from-another-aws-account-with-emrfs/.
The basic idea here is to use a credentials provider with which the access is obtained by EMRFS to access objects in S3 buckets.
You can go one step further and make the ARN for STS and buckets parameterized for the JAR created in this blog.