# Can i pass a list of arn's in "fs.s3a.stsAssumeRole.arn" ? in case of spark configs in EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

Running EMR Spark With Multiple S3 Accounts
I have an EMR Spark Job that needs to read data from S3 on one account and write to  multiple AWS accounts .

read data from the S3 (no credentials required because my EMR cluster is in the same account).

read data in the local HDFS created by step 1 and write it to multiple  S3 bucket in Multiple AWS account

Comment: With the Apache connector, you can define an S3 access/secret key pair on a per-bucket basis -- cf. section _"Configuring different S3 buckets with Per-Bucket Configuration"_ in https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Storing_secrets_with_Hadoop_Credential_Providers. I never used the AWS connector, you should check whether it supports that feature (or a similar feature).

Comment: Apache connector may cause issues with EMRFS. Will [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-instance-access-bucket/) work?

Comment: Also this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/40368998/7857701

Comment: There is work around for it which Databrick engineer has provided to create a role having trusted policy to assume on multiple account and we can switch according to the requirement in our notebook.